# ExpandAbleListView an error of Cannot instantiate the type ExpandableListAdapter

Tags: java, android, android-adapter

There is the error in code and on second line after `new` ..
on constructor of `expandablelistAdapter`. Please help me out.

ERROR IS:  Cannot instantiate the type ExpandableListAdapter ....

```
mExpandableListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.list);     
adapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this,mExpandableListView,mGroupCollection); 
mExpandableListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the Adapter ExpandableListAdapter's name this will solve your problem. Also change the constructor with the new name.